# FRTB sensitivities - which system?

Tags: sensitivities, frtb

For SBM, are sensitivities calculated in the risk engine or can they be sourced from front office (mapped to FRTB sensitivities using Jacobian)?

Comment: You mean, the FO system calculates sensitivities to IR futures, but FRTB wants sensitivies to swap rates? Or just a different list of tenors for swap rates?

Comment: Both - although I think FRTB sensitivities are based on zero coupon  rates. Also FO tenors are more granular than FRTB

Comment: Can you develop your question further? And what do you mean by using a Jacobian in this context?

Comment: @SuavestArt https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60059/dv01-on-libor-vs-sofr-basis-swaps/60062#60062

Comment: As you're probably aware, https://www.isda.org/a/hvJgE/ISDA-Responds-to-PRA-Consultation-on-Basel-3.1-Implementation.pdf pp29-220 say "Industry proposes that in cases similar to the below examples, a regulatory approval would not be required:  A. Alternative bumping methodologies under finite difference schemes.. SA sensitivities with SA tenors obtained via Jacobian transform from different tenors used for P&L reporting or Risk management ". But was there a response to ISDA?

Comment: Thanks - I had seen the paper, but I didn't see this specific proposal. I'm keen to see the PRA's response, which I think would take a while.

Comment: As far as I know, as of this writing, everyone's still waiting for various regulators to say either "this is never OK" or "this may be OK". Computationally speaking, the Jacobian introduces a little numerical noise, so the unexplained P&L (UPL) from the RTPL using the transformed FRTB sensitivities will be worse than the UPL from a P&L explanation using the original risk measures, but this shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: I see that 2 people already voted to close this question for lack of clarify. Do you mind if I try to edit / clarify it please?